# Just making sure I'm right: When is $\prod_{d|n} d=n^2$

Tags: number-theory

I'm asked which Natural numbers $n$ uphold that the multiplication of all the divisors $>=1$ of n is equal to $n^2$

I got that for that to happen there has to be only 4 different divisors of $n$ who are prime, and so $n=p_1*p_2=p_3*p_4$ can never happen, and so there no Natural numbers of that nature.

is it correct?

Comment: What is the product of the divisors of 6?

Comment: There is a big difference between prime divisors, and (the usual positive) divisors.

Comment: ok so the only numbers are those who are $p*q$ ?

Comment: But what is the product of the divisors of $4$? Or of $9$?

Comment: then $n=p*q$ and $p\not=q$? and $p,q>1$

Comment: Hint: More generally: $\prod_{d|n} d = n^{\tau(n)/2}$ where $\tau(n)$ is the number of factors of $n$.

Comment: Yeah I know that that's why the $n=p*q$ and the divisors are $1,p,q,n$ ...

Comment: But there are other solutions for $\tau(n)=4$.

Comment: wait, if i.e. $3^2$ is a divisor, it's counted once?

Comment: Well, $1,3,3^2$ are all counted, @AddarBokobza. But $3^2$ is only counted once.

Comment: What is $\prod_{d|8} d$?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's really late here I'm just in my way to bed and this Ex. is driving my crazy,I really don't see how there are other solution for τ(n)=4..and what the actual answer is..

Comment: $n=2^k$ where k is odd and $n=p*k$?........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d$ is a divisor of $n$, then so is $n/d$, right?  So we can write
$$\prod_{d\mid n}d=1\cdot d_1 \cdot d_2 \cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{n}{d_2} \cdot \frac{n}{d_1} \cdot n$$
If $n$ has an even number $2m$ of divisors, the $d_i$'s cancel out and you're left with $n^m$.  If $n$ has an odd number of divisors (i.e. $n=k^2$) then all the $d_i$'s cancel except for the $k$, so you're left with $n^m/k=k^{2m-1}$.

Thus if $\prod_{d\mid n}d=n^2$, we see that $n$ has four divisors, which is true if and only if $n=pq$ or $n=p^3$ (where $p,q$ are distinct primes).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  For the most part, you can pair up the divisors of $n$.  If there is a divisor $d$, there is also $\frac nd$.  What is their product?  How can this fail?

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem as stated, any n that can expressed as the product of 2 distinct primes would work.  Thus, 6, 10, 14, 15, 21, ... would be examples as the factors are going to be each prime and the number itself.

n is a divisor of itself is something I'd note that is where your second paragraph isn't correct.